# Fit loess smoothers for multiple groups across multiple numeric variables

Tags: r, grouping, multiple-columns, smoothing, loess

I need to fit many loess splines by the grouping variable (Animal) across multiple numeric columns (Var1, Var2), and extract these values.

I found code to do this task **one variable at a time;**

```
# Create dataframe 1
OneVarDF <- data.frame(Day = c(replicate(1,sample(1:50,200,rep=TRUE))),
                 Animal = c(c(replicate(100,"Greyhound"), c(replicate(100,"Horse")))),
                 Var1 = c(c(replicate(1,sample(2:10,100,rep=TRUE))), c(replicate(1,sample(15:20,100,rep=TRUE)))))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# Get fitted values from each model
Models <- OneVarDF %>%
  tidyr::nest(-Animal) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(m = purrr::map(data, loess, formula = Var1 ~ Day, span = 0.30),
                fitted = purrr::map(m, `[[`, "fitted")
  )

# Create prediction column
Results <- Models %>%
  dplyr::select(-m) %>%
  tidyr::unnest()
```

This ***"Results"*** dataframe is essential for downstream tasks (detrending many non-parametric distributions).

How can we achieve this with a dataframe with multiple numeric columns (code below), and extract a ***"Results"*** dataframe? Thank you.

```
# Create dataframe 2
TwoVarDF <- data.frame(Day = c(replicate(1,sample(1:50,200,rep=TRUE))),
                       Animal = c(c(replicate(100,"Greyhound"), c(replicate(100,"Horse")))),
                       Var1 = c(c(replicate(1,sample(2:10,100,rep=TRUE))), c(replicate(1,sample(15:20,100,rep=TRUE)))),
                       Var2 = c(c(replicate(1,sample(22:27,100,rep=TRUE))), c(replicate(1,sample(29:35,100,rep=TRUE)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the data in long format using. `pivot_longer`, `group_by` `Animal` and column name and apply `loess` to each combinaton.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

TwoVarDF %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Var')) %>%
  group_by(Animal, name) %>%
  mutate(model = loess(value~Day, span = 0.3)$fitted)
```

Comment: This method results in 1 fitted value column instead of 2.

Comment: @Brad See updated answer. This returns data in long format.

Comment: That's amazing, but I lost "Day". The goal is to retain "Day" because we need to subtract predictions from the observations to detrend.

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer to use `mutate` instead of `summarise` which will help to retain `Day`.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but how would one implement the `predict` function to predict, for example, the value for `Var1` for both `Greyhound` and `Horse` on `Day == 6` as there are no datapoints on `Day == 6`?

Answer (score 0):

Include a `gather()` function to proceed as similar to your previous code.

```
Models2 <- TwoVarDF %>%
  gather(varName, varVal, 3:4) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(-Animal, -varName) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(m = purrr::map(data, loess, formula = varVal ~ Day, span = 0.30),
                fitted = purrr::map(m, `[[`, "fitted")
  )
```